# Github Latex Markdown - render.githubusercontent.com equation mode

Tags: equations, markdown

I use latex formulas with Github markdown as described here:
https://gist.github.com/a-rodin/fef3f543412d6e1ec5b6cf55bf197d7b

My example equation with this link

```
<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}">
```

looks like this:

[image]

How can I switch to the equation mode so that it looks like this:

[image: expected equation]

This code does not work:

```
<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=\begin{equation}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\end{equation}">
```

It just looks like this:

[image]

The bounds should be displayed above and below and not next to the sigma.
Thanks!

Comment: In real LaTeX you can switch to display style in inline math mode with `\displaystyle`. So you could try `\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}`. (Not sure if that works. It works in LaTeX, but if I understand your link correctly, the software you are using is built on MathJax, which - despite supporting a decided LaTeX-like input syntax, isn't LaTeX and uses a very different backend to produce the output you see).

Comment: Thanks, it worked!